# what does 本体の宿り木たる霊樹が、いわば本体と言えるのだ。mean?

Tags: translation

I tried to compare it with the English version on the web novel but the content didn't match, try to search it word by word still confused.
[Here is the whole passage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZRSu.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

(I understand this is a tricky sentence, but basically [we don't do translations.](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/796/what-questions-are-not-allowed-on-japanese-language-se/799#799) Please always show your current understanding of the sentence whenever you ask something like this.)

---

> 本体の宿り木たる霊樹が、いわば本体と言えるのだ。
>   The Spiritual Tree, which is (seemingly) her "host tree", is (actually) her "core", so to speak.

The first 本体 basically refers to Traney herself (or her "spiritual body" which is covered with 魔素).

The sentence is saying Traney is not an independent being which happens to be living with the tree. Or rather, she is the tree itself. In other words, her "spiritual body" appears to be her "core" (because it's covered with mana), but her true "core" is the tree itself.